# Add multi level dropdown to Accordion bootstrap 4?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am stuck at a point where I am trying to add a multilevel submenu to the Accordion with at least 3 levels in Bootstrap 4

Like the below given example:
level zero > level one > level two

The HTML, style sheet, and JavaScript are pasted below.
I am not good with JavaScript; any help would be of great use.

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse " id="navbarContent">
       <ul id="accordion" class="accordion">
          <li>
           <div class="link">
            <i class="fa fa-database"></i>Web Design<i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i></div>
           <ul class="submenu">
            <li><a href="#">Photoshop</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
          </ul>
         </li>
      <li>
        <div class="link"><i class="fa fa-code"></i>Coding<i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i></div>
        <ul class="submenu">
         <li><a href="#">Javascript</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">jQuery</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Ruby</a></li>
      </ul>
   </li>
   <li>
     <div class="link"><i class="fa fa-mobile"></i>Devices<i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i></div>
     <ul class="submenu">
      <li><a href="#">Tablet</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Mobile</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Desktop</a></li>
   </ul>
</li>
<li>
  <div class="link"><i class="fa fa-globe"></i>Global<i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i></div>
  <ul class="submenu">
   <li><a href="#">Google</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Bing</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Yahoo</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

CSS used:

```css
 .accordion {
  width: 100%;
  /*max-width: 360px;*/
  /*margin: 30px auto 20px;*/
  background: #FFF;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.accordion .link {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  padding: 15px 15px 15px 42px;
  color: #4D4D4D;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 700;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #CCC;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.4s ease;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
}

.accordion li:last-child .link { border-bottom: 0; }

.accordion li i {
  position: absolute;
  top: 16px;
  left: 12px;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #595959;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.4s ease;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
}

.accordion li i.fa-chevron-down {
  right: 12px;
  left: auto;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.accordion li.open .link { color: #b63b4d; }

.accordion li.open i { color: #b63b4d; }

.accordion li.open i.fa-chevron-down {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(180deg);
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}

/**
 * Submenu
 -----------------------------*/


.submenu {
  display: none;
  background: #444359;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.submenu li { border-bottom: 1px solid #4b4a5e; }

.submenu a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #d9d9d9;
  padding: 12px;
  padding-left: 42px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.25s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.25s ease;
  transition: all 0.25s ease;
}

.submenu a:hover {
  background: #b63b4d;
  color: #FFF;
}
```

JavaScript used:

```js
$(function() {
   var Accordion = function(el, multiple) {
      this.el = el || {};
      this.multiple = multiple || false;

      // Variables privadas
      var links = this.el.find('.link');
      // Evento
      links.on('click', {el: this.el, multiple: this.multiple}, this.dropdown)
   }

   Accordion.prototype.dropdown = function(e) {
      var $el = e.data.el;
         $this = $(this),
         $next = $this.next();

      $next.slideToggle();
      $this.parent().toggleClass('open');

      if (!e.data.multiple) {
         $el.find('.submenu').not($next).slideUp().parent().removeClass('open');
      };
   }  

   var accordion = new Accordion($('#accordion'), false);
});
```